# Nginx - Exclude php files from htpasswd on a specified directory

Tags: php, nginx

My nginx directives:

```
location / {
    index index.html index.php;
    auth_basic "Members Only";
    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/.htpasswd_stats;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    allow 1.2.3.4;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
    auth_basic "Members Only";
    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/.htpasswd_stats;
```

}

```
location /dir/ {
    auth_basic off;
```

}

I use 'auth_basic off' option to exclude 'dir' directory from a htpasswd check.

When I try acces to http://domain/dir/ I see all files except php files because the previous directive is asking me authentication.

On apache I use 'satisfy any' option but if I use this option on nginx, doesn't work for me or I put on incorrect site.

My goal is that when I access to http://domain/dir/ there is no authentication for any file.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have separate `auth_basic` for all `.php` files.

To save your `.php` files inside `/dir/` just add this location block and *set rules inside this block according to your usecase*

```
location ~ /dir/(.+)\.php$ {
     allow 1.2.3.4;
     allow 127.0.0.1;
     deny all;
     auth_basic off;
}
```